# App Intents @Parameter with one-sided inclusive range (no upper bound)

Tags: ios, swift, sirishortcuts, appintents, app-shortcut

I want to define an AppIntent/Shortcut with a number @Parameter (of type double) that has a defined range. The range should be one-sided to only include positive numbers. Basically like the Swift range: `0...`

The `@Parameter` uses the [`inclusiveRange` type alias](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/intentparameter/inclusiverange-swift.typealias) for int/double variables …
Though, how do I define such a one-sided open range?

My current hack is to simply include a very large number in the upperBound, but there has to be a better way.

```
@Parameter(title: "Reading",
           description: "The numeric value of the reading.",
           controlStyle: .field,
           inclusiveRange: (lowerBound: 0, upperBound: 100000000),
           requestValueDialog: IntentDialog("What is the numeric value of the reading?"))
var value: Double
```

Comment: You could use `Int.max` for the upper bound :)

Comment: @JordanH It can’t build because: _Expect a compile-time constant literal_. I’ve used `Double.infinity` though, as it requires a double here …